# Is there dynamic virtual desktop on Ubuntu Unity?

Tags: virtualdesktop

As far as I know, there is virtual desktop on Ubuntu, but the number of them are constant.

Can I have the dynamic virtual desktop like Gnome3, elementary OS or Windows 10?

elementay OS's virtual desktop is the easiest for me to use.

Comment: When you say 'virtual desktops' do you mean the multiple workspaces that are manipulated by the 'Workspace Switcher'?

Comment: Ha, there is. Glad you asked the question :)

Comment: Is there any other way to see all of the windows and workspaces at the same time?